# Side effects of threading in an ASMX web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, sharepoint, thread-safety, asmx

I am trying to run SharePoint's `SPSiteDataQuery` for all web in the Site Collection for a collection of lists. The average time to get data from all sites for one list [`spWeb.GetSiteData(dataQuery)`] is anywhere between 1 to 20 seconds. The list collection can virtually have any number of lists in it.

I have implemented the threading logic as below. But I get different amount of records on every call. I am not much experienced with multi-threading architecture. What is going on, and is it worth my thinking about a better threading architecture?

```
private static Dictionary<string,string> _workTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private static Dictionary<string,string> _workspaces = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private static List<string> _processedMyWorkItems = new List<string>(); 
private static readonly object Locker = new object();
```

---

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
var processedMyWorkData = new Dictionary<string, List<XElement>>();

foreach (string selectedList in selectedLists.Distinct().OrderBy(l => l))
{
    string theSelectedList = selectedList;

    string listIds = string.Empty;

    foreach (string listId in GetListIdsFromDb(selectedList, spWeb, archivedWebs)
        .Where(listId => !selectedListIds.Contains(listId)))
    {
        selectedListIds.Add(listId);
        listIds += string.Format(@"<List ID='{0}'/>", listId);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listIds)) continue;

    dataQuery.Lists = string.Format("<Lists MaxListLimit='0'>{0}</Lists>", listIds);

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        List<XElement> processedMyWork = ProcessMyWork(selectedFields, spSite, spWeb, dataQuery, fieldTypes);

        lock (Locker)
        {
            processedMyWorkData.Add(theSelectedList, processedMyWork);
        }
    }) { Name = theSelectedList };

    threads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}

bool done = false;

while (!done)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    bool noThreadIsAlive = true;
    var threadsCompleted = new List<Thread>();

    foreach (var thread in threads)
    {
        if (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            noThreadIsAlive = false;
        }
        else
        {
            threadsCompleted.Add(thread);
        }
    }

    foreach (var thread in threadsCompleted)
    {
        threads.Remove(thread);

        string key = thread.Name;
        foreach (var xElement in processedMyWorkData[key])
        {
            result.Element("MyWork").Add(xElement);
        }

        lock (Locker)
        {
            processedMyWorkData.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    done = noThreadIsAlive;
}
```

Comment: The TPL (Task parallel library) makes this sort of work easier (or at least easier to read) than using threads manually.

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?  Seems like you could benefit from using Tasks in .NET 4.0

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: I agree. But SharePoint can't deal with .Net 4.0, yet!

Comment: What kind of application is this? Is this being run in a SharePoint web part, for instance? Also, FYI, when you throw the exception, you should include the entire exception as the InnerException in order to keep the exception chain straight.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: No. It's in ASMX service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the synchronization issue, you need to be using the WaitAll() rather than  looping around WaitOne() or polling on the IsAlive property.
To set it up, you'll need an event for each thread then add them to an array in the main thread that will uses it to wait on all the events at once. 
Note that there is a maximum of 64 events that can be monitored by WaitAll().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`static` fields in an ASMX service (or, for that matter, in any service) exist once for the entire service. That means that if you have two requests coming in at the same time, they are both writing over the same set of data.

Comment: Okay, so what would you recommend as a better approach?

Comment: I would first try this without statics and without multithreading at all. Make absolutely sure you need it for performance or scalability purposes. You don't want to play with threading with this legacy technology if you can help it. It wasn't really meant to play nicely, at least not easily.

Comment: Well, this was in production code working very well with just a few lists and sites. But the performance really degrades for each additional list and site in the collection.

Comment: What are your suggestions on passing `_processedMyWorkItems ` as a `ref` ?? Would it even work?

Comment: I don't have time to review that code today. I did notice you're using a lock around that, so that may not be the issue. Are you sure the SP API likes multiple threads?

Comment: I have been looking for the documentation that do not suggest to use multi-threading with SP API. Have not found one yet. I would really appreciate if any of you are aware of and can share such documentation.

Comment: Really, this might be a situation where multi-threading does not improve performance. I would seriously consider that possibility.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5287/discussion-between-ruby-and-john-saunders)